# Cross compile libzdb library for ARM9 architecture

Tags: debian, arm, cross-compilation

I am using AM1808 ARM9-based micro processor for my project on Ubuntu v10.04 using G++ compiler.

I am using sqlite3 database for data management.

My application needs multiple simultaneous access to database.

I found I need to implement connection pooling method to work efficiently.

I googled a bit and found that Libzdb library is available for connection pooling and it is open source.

I don't know how to cross compile this library for ARM9 architecture.

How I can do this ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set up a [cross compilation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_compiler) environment. That means installing a compiler and associated tools that run on your PC and compiles programs for the ARM9 processor.

It's not clear in your question whether your device is running Ubuntu 10.04, or your development machine is, or both.

Recent versions of Ubuntu (including 12.04) provide a cross-compilation toolchain targeting ARM Linux — [`binutils-arm-linux-gnueabi`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/devel/binutils-arm-linux-gnueabi), [`g++-arm-linux-gnueabi`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/devel/g++-arm-linux-gnueabi), etc. If your development machine is running Ubuntu 10.04, you can install [Emdebian](http://www.emdebian.org/). [Linaro](http://www.linaro.org/) is another popular ARM toolchain.

Comment: thank you. I have already Cross compilation environment setup in my UBUNTU 10.04. First i need to build libzdb with C99 compiler then i need to cross compile that for ARM9.right ?

Comment: You need to compile libzdb with your cross-compilation environment. Come to think of it, that should be the same environment that you're compiling your own code with. I don't see what is blocking you, maybe you should clarify your question to say precisely what your problem is.